# Basic HTML not getting rendered (latest MAMP used)

Tags: html, css, mamp

I am writing an HTML page and stored using MAMP (latest) but the HTML is not getting rendered when opening the browser(s) instead coming as pure HTML code.

Why?

Comment: Have you any effort or research to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a little while back.
Posting the code would be helpful but this is what I suggest:

1. Make sure the code folder is placed in the htdocs folder of MAMP.
2. Make sure internet connection is secure and the application is fully downloaded.
3. Make sure `<!DOCTYPE html>` Tag is apparent and the structural tags:

`<html> <head> <title> Title </title> </head> <body> </body> </html>`

are included.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Your title here</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor=”fffjff”>

</body>

</html>